# Updating/Saving post meta data of multiple posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a plugin that does the following. (Would have posted an image, but not allowed)

Updates the meta data of multiple posts in a single category using drag and drop ordering from a table.

The table is displayed on all posts in this one category, displaying the id of all the posts, the title of all the posts and the meta data of all the posts defined by it's key and value.

jQuery does the reordering and updates the order in the table, say from 1 to however many posts are in this category, so if there is 10 posts the values in the table are updated from 1 - 10.

What I need to do now is update the post meta value of every post in the table with the correct value displayed in say column 3 of the table.

Using the default function:

```
update_post_meta( $post->ID, Post_Order, $_POST['Post_Order']);
```

This sets the meta to the last row value in the table.

How can I go through each row, grab the post id and key value from that row, then update the corresponding posts meta data.

Thanks

**Edit**

Five minutes after posting this I sorted it out.
Here's the answer, prob not the correct way to do it but it works really well.

```
$args = array(
          'order'           => 'ASC',
          'post_type'       => 'post',
          'post_status'     => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page'  => '',
          'category_name'   => 'Customers',
          'meta_key'        => 'Post_Order',
          'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num'
        );

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $postid = get_the_ID();
            update_post_meta( $postid, 'Post_Order', $_POST['Post_Order_' . $postid]  );
        endwhile;
```

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you can answer your own question below instead of editing the post

Comment: Can you post the full code to this? I am intrigued as to how it works!